# Woocommerce Filter customization (rounding vs floor)

Tags: wordpress, filter, woocommerce, rounding, floor

I have this filter in Woocommerce source code:

```
$this->total = max( 0, apply_filters( 'woocommerce_calculated_total', round( $this->cart_contents_total + $this->tax_total + $this->shipping_tax_total + $this->shipping_total + $this->fee_total, $this->dp ), $this ) );
```

I want to apply this change with my filter but I can't understand how.

```
$this->total = max( 0, apply_filters( 'woocommerce_calculated_total', floor(( $this->cart_contents_total + $this->tax_total + $this->shipping_tax_total + $this->shipping_total + $this->fee_total) * 100)/100, $this ) );
```

Any help will be appreciated. A greeting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done!

```
function custom_round_function( $total, $cart ) {

$total = floor(($cart->cart_contents_total + $cart->tax_total + $cart->shipping_tax_total + $cart->shipping_total + $cart->fee_total) * 100)/100;

return $total;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_calculated_total', 'custom_round_function', 10, 2 );
```